# How to replace the last matched word using regex in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.8

Using regex function in python i couldn't able to replace the words/sentence which are repeated.

From the example below, How to replace the word which is repeated multiple times, i.e., Peter Piper is repeated more than once in the statement and how to replace the last Peter Piper:

> ran_ln = "Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled peppers
>   A peck of pickled peppers Peter Piper picked
>   If Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled peppers
>   Where’s the peck of pickled peppers Peter Piper picked?"

The thing what i tried is:

```
 re.sub("Piper", "aaaaa", ran_ln)
```

But when i use this function all the Peter Piper word is replaced.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read about "negative lookahead" in the Python docs about regex.

Answer (score 1):

[Negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) would be your friend.

Please also note, that [raw strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html) are recommended to use in regex patterns.

```
out =  re.sub(r'(Peter Piper)(?:(?!.*\1))'gm, 'aaaaa', ran_ln)
```

Edit: Deleted misleading dot typo, as Diadistis suggested.

Comment: Not sure why you added the extra `.` or the non-capturing group. As it is right now it also replaces an extra character. I'd change it to `(Peter Piper)(?!.*\1)`